# Scene from a PK Dick novel: a subjective world with a huge God-eye in the sky

Tags: story-identification, novel, philip-k-dick

In the novel, which I thought was *Ubik*, a party of characters has an accident, and progress through the subjective worlds of each in turn. One of them is a bible-thumping believer, and the staring eye-in-the-sky (a primitive monotheistic idea of 'God') occurs in this person's 'world'.

If anyone is interested, I'm trying to relocate this scene because I'm writing an analysis of Stanisław Lem's *Solaris*. One section will contrast the absolute Other as a punctum or point in the universe — for example, Jorge Luis Borges's "The Aleph", with scenarios where this Other is 'in your face' — 'half the sky' or 'half the visible world'.

Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 19):

[*Eye in the Sky*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9367), a 1957 novel by [Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick).

From the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_in_the_Sky_%28novel%29):

> After an accident at the Belmont Bevatron, eight people are forced into several different alternate universes. These ersatz universes are later revealed to be solipsistic manifestations of each individual's innermost fears and prejudices, bringing the story in line with Dick's penchant for subjective realities. As well as his future discussions of theology and fears about McCarthy-era authoritarianism, the novel skewers several human foibles.
>
> The title refers to the eye of God, who appears as a character in the universe of religious fundamentalist Arthur Sylvester.

[image]

Comment: Nice! One of the PKD I haven't read yet ... putting it on the to-read pile.